# Trigger After Insert writes a copy of all rows to audit file

Tags: mysql, triggers

First time that I am tying to use triggers in mysql. I have no problems with the AFTER  UPDATE which writes exactly one record to my audit file. 
But when I do an AFTER INSERT, it writes a copy of **all** records from the original table to the audit table. I only what it to write the one changed record to the audit file. I guess it is because of the 'For each row', but all examples I found contain this command. What am I missing?

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertafter AFTER INSERT ON `delete4try`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO delete4try_audit 
SELECT h . * , NULL , NOW( )  FROM delete4try h
```

Answer (score 0):

because you're selecting with no WHERE clause, 
you might want to use NEW.col1,NEW.col2 for example and take out the FROM delete4try

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertafter AFTER INSERT ON `delete4try`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO delete4try_audit 
SELECT NEW.col1,NEW.col2,NULL,NOW()
```

col1 and col2 are just samples replace them with your actual column names.

Comment: for example, if your delete4try had a column called col1, NEW.col1 would return the value used for the insert of col1 for the new row that was just inserted